# How to map the Gradient Texture based on the loose parts of a single object?

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders, procedural, vector-mapping

Is it possible to map the `Gradient Texture` in a way that no matter the position of the mesh on the space? So $0$ will always be at one end of the mesh and $1$ at the other end.

In this case, I have a single object with meshes that are not in contact with each other. The `Gradient Texture` ends up mapped from the lowest point of the geometry to the highest.

[image]

But the final result should be something similar to this: *a single object where each loose part goes from $0$ to $1$*.

[image]

Comment: I think you can add another uv map to position each loose part and use uv as texture coordinate.